# How to create middleware with multiple role in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'am using Sentinel package, for example I've created middleware `PCMiddleware`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $roles = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2); 

        foreach ($roles as $role) {

            if(Sentinel::check() && Sentinel::getUser()->inRole($role)){
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('admin.errors');
            }
        }    
    }
```

**Route**:

```
$route->get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'AdminController@dashboard'])->middleware('role_check:member,hrd,super-admin');
```

and I've created user too with role `hrd`, which is any user with hrd role can access dashboard but when I loggedin endup with `404` how can I be able to access `/dashboard` even though I only have hrd role ?

maybe like this if user has any of these 3 role then he can access the route,

Comment: 404 would usually be a not found, the response code for authentication or authorization issues usually wouldn't be a 404.  does that route work without any auth checks?

Comment: @lagbox exactly, any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel already there is a way of transferring parameters for the middlewares. You can read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#middleware-parameters)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $roles = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2); 

   $status = false;

    foreach ($roles as $role) {

        if(Sentinel::check() && Sentinel::getUser()->inRole($role)){
            $status = true;
             break;
        }
    }    

      if ($status) {
           return $next($request);
       } 
     return redirect()->route('admin.errors');
}
```

In this example, your code will work if at least one of the passed parameters exists